# Laravel-echo in Vue returning "private is not a function"

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, quasar

I'm trying to build a Chat App that use `Laravel Broadcast` with `laravel-echo` and `pusher` but when I'm listening to the channel it returns `laravel_echo__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.private is not a function`

here's my script:

```
<script>
  import ConfirmationModal            from "../pages/User/ConfirmationModal";
  import Message                      from '../models/Message';
  import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

  export default {
    name: 'UserLayout',
    components : {
      ConfirmationModal
    },
    data: () => ({
      isLoading : false,
      user : {},
      drawer: false,
      rawConversations : {},
    }),
    mounted () {
      this.user  = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
      this.fetchConversations();
    },
    created () {
        Echo.private("userStatus").listen("StatusEvent", e => {
             console.log('Event listen CommentSent');
         });
    }
  }
</script>
```

here's my directory. BTW, I'm using `Quasar Framework` for my CSS and directory `Laravel` and `Vue` is separate.

[image]

Comment: Did you instantiate echo as described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo)?

Comment: You did not instantiate Laravel Echo.